# CheckBox de tabela no JavaFx seleciona sozinho quando mexo na barra de rolagem

Tags: javafx, checkbox, table

Olá! Estou aprendendo javafx e tenho uma tabela com uma coluna de checkbox, quando a aplicação inicia ele lista certinho nas linhas da tabela. O problema é que quando seleciono os dois primeiros por exemplo ele seleciona sozinhos outros, e conforme vou descendo a barra de rolagem cada hora um está selecionado. Essa é a minha classe com os getters e setters.

```
 package model.domain;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;



public class op_inicial {

    private SimpleBooleanProperty selecao;
    private String operacao;
    private Double valor;
    private String situacao;
    private Double valorDaParcela;
    private String modalidade;
    private String data_contratacao;



    public op_inicial(String operacao, Double valor, String situacao, Double valorDaParcela, String modalidade, String data_contratacao) {
        this.selecao = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
        this.operacao = operacao;
        this.valor = valor;
        this.situacao = situacao;
        this.valorDaParcela = valorDaParcela;
        this.modalidade = modalidade;
        this.data_contratacao = data_contratacao;
    }

    public String getModalidade() {
        return modalidade;
    }

    public void setModalidade(String modalidade) {
        this.modalidade = modalidade;
    }

    public String getData_contratacao() {
        return data_contratacao;
    }

    public void setData_contratacao(String data_contratacao) {
        this.data_contratacao = data_contratacao;
    }


    public op_inicial() {

    }

    public Double getValorDaParcela() {
        return valorDaParcela;
    }

    public void setValorDaParcela(Double valorDaParcela) {
        this.valorDaParcela = valorDaParcela;
    }

    public op_inicial(Double valorDaParcela) {
        this.valorDaParcela = valorDaParcela;
    }

    public Double valorDaParcela (){
        return valorDaParcela;
    }

    public SimpleBooleanProperty getSelecao() {
        return selecao;
    }

    public void setSelecao(SimpleBooleanProperty selecao) {
        this.selecao = selecao;
    }




    public String getOperacao() {
        return operacao;
    }

    public String operacao() {
        return operacao;
    }

    public void setOperacao(String operacao) {
        this.operacao = operacao;

    }

    public Double getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public Double valor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(Double valor) {
        this.valor = valor;

    }

    public String getSituacao() {
        return situacao;
    }

    public String situacao() {
        return situacao;
    }

    public void setSituacao(String situacao) {
        this.situacao = situacao;

    }

}
```

E aqui eu monto a tabela, estou usando o Scene Builder. Estou populando a tabela com um array list que pego de um sistema. A tabela monta corretamente com os checkBox, mas na hora de selecionar que ele fica com esse erro e quando organizo uma coluna por maior valor a coluna do checkBox não ordena junto com as outras. Se alguém puder me ajudar por gentileza :))))).

```
 public void preencheTabelas(TextField txtChave, String mci) throws PropertyVetoException, Throwable {

        try {

            listop = captura_sistema.operacoes(txtChave, mci);

            //=============  primeira tabela  =========
            coluna_check_selecao1.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(coluna_check_selecao1));
            coluna_check_selecao1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("selecao"));
            coluna_Operacao1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("operacao"));
            coluna_valorParcela1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("valorDaParcela"));
            coluna_Valor1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("valor"));
            coluna_situacao1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("situacao"));
            coluna_Modalidade1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("modalidade"));
            coluna_DataContratacao1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("data_contratacao"));

            observableListOperacao = FXCollections.observableArrayList(listop);

            tableOperacoes.setItems(observableListOperacao);
```

Comment: pode adicionar parte do código onde vc declarou as variaveis e os tipos do tableView e tableColumns???